# What's the different between containing and like in JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

If I wanna use fuzzy select , It seems wrong when I used like ,I have to use containing . So What's the different between containing and like in JPA?

Comment: JPA has no "containing". `LIKE` is for Strings. Perhaps you should update your question with example JPQL of what you mean for both

Answer (score 1):

Both are very similar, according Spring documentation on Container parameters are bound wrapped in % and on Like not. So if you want same result, try to add % to parameters on query with Like

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details